# invalid hook call error after selfclosing one component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-dom

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

> ./src/index.js/< src/index.js:8
>
> 5 | import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';    6 | import
> "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";    7 | import
> { BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
>
> > 8 | ReactDOM.render(    9 |      10 |        11 |   ,

After including navigation component in App.js file invalid hook call error is coming below is my app.js file code

```
import React from "react";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import About from "./components/About";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Navigation from "./Navigation";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Navigation />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

after removing navigation component error is not coming below is index.js file code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App/>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more: 
reportWebVitals();
```

navigation.js

```
import { Navbar, Nav, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import React from 'react'

export default function Navigation() {
    return (
        <>
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect fixed="top" expand="sm" bg="dark" variant="dark">
            <Container>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                <Nav>
                <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/about">About</Nav.Link>

                </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Container>
        </Navbar>
        </>
    )
}
```

can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after moving the navigation.js file into the components folder it is working i think that is the reason for two instances of react[image]
[image]